# How to get the pshome path for 64-bits?

Tags: powershell

The path to home folder in 32-bits is accessible using the `$PSHome` variable (`c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`).

How to access the variable that contains the path to the 64-bits version (`c:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`) ?

**EDIT**

As Jeff Zeitlin explained in the answer marked as correct, this question is invalid...

Comment: See [this ServerFault answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/678529/powershell-script-not-working-when-launched-from-ssh-or-winexe-from-a-mac-or-l/678530#678530)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got it backwards - on 64-bit Windows, `C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32` is for 64-bit stuff; `C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64` is for 32-bit stuff. This is because Microsoft chose to make the "main" directory `SYSTEM32` for backward compatibility; the new 32-bit folder is called `SYSWOW64` as shorthand for "System for Windows-on-Windows64".

However, to answer your actual question: If you are running 64-bit PowerShell, `$PSHome` points to the 64-bit home folder, `C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`; if you are running 32-bit PowerShell ("Windows Powershell (x86)"), `$PSHome` will point to `C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`. I'm not sure if there is a way to get the equivalent of `$PSHome-for-the-other-bittedness`.

Comment: I'm working with .net for 8+ years and i didn't knew that... I will go to the corner and cry a little....

Comment: Thanks for the explanation btw :)

Comment: Regarding syswow64, wow, you just blew my mind.

Answer (score 2):

That changes depending on whether you're running the 32-bit or 64-bit version of PowerShell!

### 32-bit

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

[image: 32-bit PowerShell $PSHome]

### 64-bit

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

[image: 64-bit PowerShell $PSHome]

---

### Detecting 64-bit mode

Use this code to identify whether you're running in 64-bit mode or not!

```
[Environment]::Is64BitProcess
```

Comment: This is backward. See my answer below.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin you're right - answer updated (included `[Environment]::Is64BitProcess` in screenies, too)