# Using x64 ODBC source from x86 Powershell console

Tags: powershell, odbc, connection-string

Is there a way to acess x64 ODBC DSN via x86 Powershell/Powershell ISE window?

Right now if I try so I get an error that DSN/driver is not found, and it's true because there is no such driver/dsn in x86 ODBC store.

The only way to achive this is to open x64 powershell console from `SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`

Could I explicitly set driver location from x64 store?
My connection string right now looks like this:

```
$Connection = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = "driver={Adaptive Server Enterprise};dsn=$DSN;db=$DefaultDatabase;na=$ServerName,$Port;uid=$uid;pwd=$pwd;"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090728/how-to-get-the-pshome-path-for-64-bits/42090886 ?

Comment: If PowerShell remoting is enable, then you can just `Enter-PSSession . -EnableNetworkAccess`. Or you can create out of process runspace ([C# example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34919564)) and use it to invoke commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

32-bit x86 processes, including x86 Powershell, cannot directly use 64-bit x86_64 libraries including ODBC DSNs/drivers.

64-bit x86_64 processes, including x86_64 Powershell, cannot directly use 32-bit x86 libraries including ODBC DSNs/drivers.

You can use a "Multi-Tier" bridging solution, which uses TCP/IP or other networking communications layer to communicate between 32-bit and 64-bit environments, such as [this one](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-odbc-mt/) from [my employer, OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/) ... or you can acquire a [32-bit ODBC driver for Sybase ASE](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-sybase-st/).